# Directory Pathing

Tags: php, jquery, directory

I have a problem with pathing my files to each other. are all directory pathing format the same? because in external links Ex: `<script type="text/javascript" src="file_js/friendList.js"></script>` is not the same with `<img src="../FriendsList/image/defaultboysmall.png" />` but both code works. ex: `../folder/file.php` or `folder/file.php`.

Example:

```
$.getJSON('/data_php/getFriends.php', function(data) {

$.getJSON('../data_php/getFriends.php', function(data) {

$.getJSON('data_php/getFriends.php', function(data) {
```

this line codes here doesn't work for me, I don't know why it acts this way. Please help, I'm no good with Directory Paths.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getJSON` and its `ajax` ilk are based on urls, not the file system.  You need to be using an appropriate path relative to the document root of the website.

Comment: oh. Sorry. I ain't that good with this things. Will you tell me more about this Relative Pathing.

Comment: Your website document root must be somewhere at `~/www` or `~/public_html`, or something.  You should basically treat that as root for the purposes of URL requests to the website.

Comment: Root you mean like the starting Main folder? `http://localhost/FriendsList/friendList.php` like this right?

Answer (score 0):

It must by url, no path.
I think that better way is put path into html by php. After select this path and put into ajax callback.

example:
html:

```
<p data-link='<?= link_to_fiends() ?>'>hi</p>
```

js:

```
var link = $('p').data('link');
$.getJSON(link,function(data){});
```